# How to webscrape something that doesn't have an attribute or anything attached to it in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im trying to webscrape electricity prices from a website: https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/en/Market-data1/#/nordic/table. When I try to find the web element for the date and the price this is what it looks like:

The first date:

```
td class="row-name ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="tableData.dataType == 0" 
ng-bind-html="tableData.axis.y.items[$index].name">03-01-2023</td
```

Here I wanna access the 03-01-2023 which is the date but I can't seem to access it?

The full Xpath for this is: `/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`

The first price:

```
td ng-repeat="column in row | visibleColumns:enableFilter:tableData:visibleEntities" 
ng-class="{ 'highlight-value': highlightColumn(column), 'preliminary': column.preliminary, 'row-name-2': $index == 0 &amp;&amp; tableData.includeUKTime, }" class="" ng-bind-html="column.value">135,05</td
```

Here I wanna access 135,05 but how?

Xpath: `/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]`

What I tried:

I tried returning the class and the tag name thinking it would return the date and the price but it didn't work instead it gave me:

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="*random characters*",
element"*random characters*")
```

So it gave me some session and web element information but not the date or price

Code in Python (Tried returning the whole table of dates and prices):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/en/Market-data1/#/nordic/table"

PATH = "C:/PATH"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get(url)

Date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "datatable"))
        )

print(Date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, it will print all the values from the table:

```
page_url = "https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/en/Market-data1/#/nordic/table"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(page_url)

table_rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//tr[contains(@ng-repeat,'row in tableData')]")

table_cols = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(.//tr[contains(@ng-repeat,'row in tableData')])[1]/td")

for row in range(len(table_rows)):
    for col in range(len(table_cols)):
        print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//tr[contains(@ng-repeat,'row in tableData')])["+ str(row + 1) + "]/td[" + str(col + 1) + "]").text, end = " | ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
04-01-2023 | 87,86 | 73,41 | 73,41 | 73,41 | 73,41 | 99,96 | 58,94 | 73,41 | 109,08 | 109,08 | 109,08 | 71,86 | 71,86 | 51,79 | 101,68 | 101,68 | 101,68 | 142,75 | 88,60 | 58,94 | 97,74 | 99,89 | 
03-01-2023 | 135,05 | 101,04 | 101,04 | 132,76 | 132,76 | 132,76 | 145,95 | 132,76 | 147,07 | 147,07 | 147,07 | 103,91 | 103,91 | 75,71 | 132,76 | 132,76 | 132,76 | 147,28 | 145,95 | 145,95 | 146,05 | 145,86 | 
02-01-2023 | 127,36 | 116,51 | 116,51 | 123,26 | 123,26 | 123,26 | 124,13 | 123,43 | 141,86 | 141,86 | 141,86 | 121,02 | 121,02 | 80,72 | 123,37 | 123,37 | 123,37 | 126,36 | 125,65 | 123,82 | 124,58 | 131,08 | 
...
...
```

Comment: Ok! I think the only thing I forgot to do was to write .text at the end of my driver.find_element.